# Is there a way to get data from DataGridView control in wpf application?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a windows form control that I need to use in a wpf application. The control in the DataGridView, but when I try to access data that the user have inserted inside the control I always get null values.

I've already created the control using a WindowsFormHost control in xaml, and initialize columns inside the window main class. I've tried using the code that I have already use in windows form application to get data.

This is the initialization of the control

```
<WindowsFormsHost>
    <wf:DataGridView x:Name="data"></wf:DataGridView>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

Next I initialize columns with this code:

```
data.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
data.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn c1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
c1.HeaderText = "Name";
c1.Name = "description";
data.Columns.Add(c1);


DataGridViewTextBoxColumn c2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
c2.HeaderText = "Quantity";
c2.Name = "quantity";
data.Columns.Add(c2);
```

Now the grid is initialized correctly, and if I take a look to the wpf window everything is ok and created in the correct way. I can also insert data and perform resizing operations over columns and rows. Now I have a button with which I should get the data the user insert:

```
//because count also the header as row
if (data.Rows.Count > 1)
{
    int counter = 1;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in data.Rows)
    {
        int counter = 1;
        //do not count the header
        if(counter > 1)
        {
            string name = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string q = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

But at this point a null pointer exception is raised because the content of row.Cells[0].Value is null (even if data are present). The returned error is System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get has returned null. Notice that the row count works fine, because if I insert a new row it counts 2 (header and new row).

Please let me know if you have a workoaround to overcome this issue.

Comment: IMO you would have much less friction if you just use WPF controls. What is your reason for needing a winforms grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How to handle DataGrid (WPF)

1st. Declare a Type which will represent the rows:

```
public class RowType
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

2st. Initialize DataGrid and add Columns and Rows:

```
DataGridTextColumn c1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
c1.Header = "Name";
c1.Binding = new Binding("Name");
data.Columns.Add(c1);

DataGridTextColumn c2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
c2.Header = "Quantity";
c2.Binding = new Binding("Quantity");
data.Columns.Add(c2);

data.Items.Add(new RowType() { Name = "a", Quantity = "one" });
data.Items.Add(new RowType() { Name = "b", Quantity = "two" });
```

3rd. Read the rows:

```
RowType tmp = data.Items[0] as RowType;

MessageBox.Show(tmp.Name + " " + tmp.Quantity);
```

#### Accessing Values from DataGridView (WinForms)

Value could be `null`. You can't perform a `ToString()` on `null`.

Add a "?" to fix this:

```
string name = row.Cells[0].Value?.ToString();
string q = row.Cells[1].Value?.ToString();
```

Smaller example for the [`?`-Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators):

```
string tmp = null;

string x1 = tmp?.ToString(); // Works! x1 == null
string x2 = tmp.ToString(); // throws exception
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem is not the fact that is null, but the fact that what inserted is not readed correctly by the method. Even if data are inserted and present the returned value is always null. Everything is always set to null when try to access.

Comment: I'm confused why you use `DataGridView` in `WPF`. You should use `DataGrid`. Added an example how to use it.

Comment: The reason is that I was using it on a old project and I tried to reuse it on the wpf update version. Data grid possess the same capabilities? In particular I'm intrested in the auto-row adding when user insert data. Is there a property or I should manage everything with trigger events? In few words what I need is a direct editing on the rows of the grid, with the user possibility to insert unseen data.